# pandas left join - why more results?

Tags: python, pandas, join, dataframe, left-join

How is it possible that a pandas left join like

```
df.merge(df2, left_on='first', right_on='second', how='left')
```

increases the data frame from  221309 to 1388680 rows?

## edit

shape of df 1 (221309, 83)

shape of df2 (7602, 6)

Comment: We need to know how many rows both of them have

Comment: Does `df` or `df2` contain duplicate keys?

Comment: I checked that for df2 and had pandas drop all the keys. @Maxu no this is the number of the merged dataframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [@JonClements has already said in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40002355/pandas-left-join-why-more-results/40002535#comment67282514_40002355) it's a result of duplicated entries in the columns used for merging/joining. Here is a small demo:

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
   a   b
0  1  11
1  1  12
2  2  21

In [6]: df2
Out[6]:
   a    c
0  1  111
1  1  112
2  2  221
3  2  222
4  3  311

In [7]: df.merge(df2, on='a', how='left')
Out[7]:
   a   b    c
0  1  11  111
1  1  11  112
2  1  12  111
3  1  12  112
4  2  21  221
5  2  21  222
```

Comment: I see. Probably it is a caching problem because initially there were duplicates.

Comment: It's not a caching problem @GeorgHeiler